# Position of Text in a TextBox

Tags: winapi, vb6

Hi I have a textbox containing some text. I am looking to replicate the red spelling mistake squiggle type behaviour.

Using WinAPI I can

- draw the squiggle between 2 points.
- find out the height and width of
  the word to be "squiggled".

What is the api call (or perhaps the methodology if it is more than a single api call) to find the position of that word in the text box so that I can position the sqiggle undeneath it.

Also, what are the messages I need to trap to ensure that the squiggle is redrawn. I'm currently only using WM_PAINT, which obviously isn't good enough.

EDIT (3 Sept 2012):
FYI, Here's where I got to so far. Needs a lot of refining but shows basic principles

https://gist.github.com/3607272

Many thx

S

Comment: This is not an option, the VB6 TextBox control does not support custom drawing at all.  You'll need to shop for some kind of other control to do this.  That should be hard, it is too ancient.

Comment: Thx Hans. Well I'm using a third party control which exposes an hWnd (Doesn't the VB6 text box?) so I can get its hdc and can subclass it. Can you explain a bit more as to why you think it wouldn't be possible?  This link (http://www.codedblog.com/2007/09/17/owner-drawing-a-windowsforms-textbox/) shows some .net calls achieving something similar. I assume they are delegating to the winapi at some point. I was thinking I just need to know which calls are being made. eg does the TextBoxAPIHelper.PosFromChar send an EM_POSFROMCHAR message?

Comment: Try using scintilla control, its free and opensource. It takes care of all your such requirements. http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html

Comment: @shubhansh - thx, but unfortunately I am mod'ing an existing product which is tied to this 3rd party control so don't have the option to strip it out.

Comment: The "Microsoft Rich Textbox Control" is more dynamic than the standard text box and may be better in this case, not tested though.

Comment: @Matt, thx, but as I said, there is a legacy issue whereby I can't swap controls

Comment: @SimonWoods In that case I'm with Hans, although that link makes for very interesting reading, I can't see how to apply it in this instance, sorry : (

Comment: @Matt, - thx again. I was thinking that the article provides the methodology for underlining with a squiggle. I was hoping be able to translate the article to pure winapi calls.

Comment: @Matt ... and yes ... this question is from the 90s! ;)

Comment: Why is `WM_PAINT` obviously not good enough? (beyond your statement that it isn't)

Comment: @Deanna ... maybe it isn't obvious then ... I was thinking that I'd need to cater for situations where I was changing existing text and would want to selective add/remove squiggles from individual words. My initial thought was WM_PAINT would be too general. I really need to test on key down as well (at least for spaces and check the previos word etc)... afaics

Comment: @SimonWoods Handling `WM_PAINT` allows you to get the control to do it's default drawing, then allowing you to draw the squiggle on top. You can do the calculations on change. There was a way to get the scroll position but I can't remember it off hand :(

Comment: @Deanna - thx .. when I have subclassed the control ... I find that the paint event isn't firing when I keydown. Maybe I am doing something wrong. So I am having to catch the keydown as well and work out which squiggles I need to add remove. Wrt Scroll position, I haven't considered that yet ... sounds bad though.

Answer (score 1):

What might work is using an auto-sized label. Make sure the fonts in the label and textbox are identical.

1. Detect the number of rows that are before the sentence containing the misspelled word.
2. Fill the label caption with the number linefeeds (`vbcrlf`) you got from question 1.
3. Append the words from the misspelled line (up to the misspelled word) to the labels caption.
4. The label size should now be identical with the beginning of the misspelled word.

Example text:

`This is my first line.

And my second line.

And over here i have my mispeled word.`

Label caption output should be (ignore the dots, they are empty lines):

`.

.

And over here i have my`

The labels height and width should match the position in the textbox, unless you have scrollbars. If the textbox has borders then you should add a fixed value to the height and width to get an exact match.